# iPad app: add a button, other button's text stops displaying

Tags: xcode, ipad, button

I am developing an app for the iPad. The app implements a set of independent functions.  As I add a function I also add a button with a simple text title in the app's only ViewController view to invoke the function.  These buttons are the only GUI elements on the app's view.  I've been doing this for a few weeks without problems. I'm using storeyboards.

When I added the 19th button, it looked fine on the storeyboard, but when I ran the app on my iPad, four of the buttons had no text or a thin line of black dots.  I can move the buttons around and resize them and sometimes get more to display and/or other buttons' text will stop displaying correctly.

Each button contains a simple text title, e.g., "Copy" "Open" "Read" "Write", etc.  The only slightly unusual titles are "Pwrite-1" "Pwrite-2" and "mkdir/stat".  The 19th button I added has the title "Chdir".

The buttons always look fine on the storeyboard, so it looks to me like it's a build issue.

Anyone seen anything like this and know a workaround?